# Shell script with pipes not working in crontab

Tags: shell-script, cron, pipe

I have a shell script that works fine when run manually, but fails when run through the crontab.
The script essentially does as follows:

```
Python script to get audio data and pipe to stdout | ffmpeg the data from stdin and pipe to stdout | stream the data from stdin
```

When run through crontab the streaming fails, complaining that there is no data at stdin (`...No (more) data available on standard input`).

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/330717) answer which seems to allude to the issue of file descriptors in crontab, but I would appreciate some more details on the problem and the best way to get around it.

**EDIT:**
Troubleshooting the issue by trying each individual command separately shows that the issue starts in the python script which complains:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr"
```

instead of outputting audio data. Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955138/addressing-sys-excepthook-error-in-bash-script) and [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2012-April/089278.html) (added sys.stdout.flush()  to the end of the file) I can see the actual error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/*username*/testing.py", line 109, in <module>
    sys.stdout.flush()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

So perhaps it's more of a python issue..though from the error it stil seems to have to do with stdin/stdout

Comment: Please show us the exact command/script and the exact error message. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-Man Done, though not sure how much information it adds in this specific instance, which is why I left it general.

Comment: It points a finger at the `my_python_file.py` script. Can you capture the raw output from that script (in `cron`) and write it to a file? Something like `/usr/bin/python /home/tzvi/my_python_file.py >/tmp/my_file.dat 2>/tmp/my_file.err`

Comment: @roaima Done. Thank you, I'm sorry I didn't think to consider that the problem could have started somewhere else--though it does still seem to me to be related to piping in cron

Comment: Fixed. I will try to update with an answer later

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955138/addressing-sys-excepthook-error-in-bash-script or possibly http://bugs.python.org/issue11380#msg248579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue really was the python file and cron, but not an issue with file descriptors (stdin/stdout)  in the way I had expected.

Rather, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30311866/1941570) having a line asking for user input while running through cron was causing the issue. I solved the issue by removing the request for user input as for me it was unnecessary.